# How to add a js file to a rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a js file which is part of a purchased theme to my rails project.

In my `assets.rb` file I have

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(mvpready-core.js)
```

In my application.js I have

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.
//= require mvpready-core
//= require_tree .
```

At the end of my user.html.erb I have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

But when I load the page console gives me the error

```
ReferenceError: mvpready_core is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I debug this?

Comment: Did you place the javascript file in `app/assets/javascripts`?

Comment: Yes I put the js files in app/assets/javascripts

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to tell anything to the `assets.rb` file. 
The proper way of integrating a purchased theme is to put the required assets files in the vendor folder of your rails project directory. The vendor folder is specially for the third party plugins such as `bootstrap`. So what you need to do is as follows:

**STEP 1:**

- Copy and paste the necessary JS and CSS files into the particular folders of the assets inside vendor folder.

**STEP 2:**

- Require those files in to the project's manifest file i.e `application.js` and `application.css` files.

You can find `manifest` files here:
`app -> assets -> javascripts -> application.js` and  `app -> assets -> stylesheets -> application.css`

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you understand a little bit more. Ruby on Rails has some magick that goes on in the background where you do not need to add anything to

```
assets.rb
```

once you have setup your new project all you need to do is put the javascript file into:

```
/app/assets/javascripts/mvpread-core.js
```

When you start the rails server it will autoload anything you have in following directories:

```
/app/assets/javascripts/mvpread-core.js
/app/assets/images/mvpread-core.png
/app/assets/stylesheets/mvpread-core.css
```

Now if the javascript has path's in it linking to images, other javascripts, and other stylesheets you will need to search through the source code and make sure that it is looking for the file in this url path structure:

```
/assets{javascripts|images|stylesheets}
```

Also as @Taylor Galeser asked did you put the file in /app/assets/javascripts ?
This is all a very overly simplistic explanation on what Ruby on Rails does automatically for you but it should help you get what is going on behind the scenes better.